# Observing multiple action Buttons Shiny

Tags: r, events, button, eventtrigger, action-button

I'm new to R development and I am struggling a little bit how I can achieve that. I have a piece of code where I observe two action buttons waiting for clicks on them. Now I want know in the if statement which one of them was clicked, but my implementation is not working. I already searched some possible solution but I was not able to find it. Someone can give me a little help with that? Thanks!

```
observeEvent({c(input[["button1"]], input[["button2"]])}, {        

      output$mean<- renderPlotly({            

       if(input[["button1"]]){ 

           output_mean(out(), start_date(), geo(), language(), grupo(), TRUE, "button1")

        }else if(input[["button2"]]){

           output_mean(out(), start_date(), geo(), language(), grupo(), TRUE, "button2")

        }
      })

    #}
  })
```

Comment: Why do you nest a `render*` within an `observe*`? Seems rather redundant and complicating. (This doesn't solve your problem, but it may prevent others later.)

Comment: @r2evans I am sorry but I did not know about that. I am new in here so I just did know about that. But I already accepted the answers for my previous questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- `render*` functions are inherently reactive, so they should not be nested within another. In this case, it is already able to react without adding anything.
- Action buttons work by incrementing their value each time it is pressed. This means if a user clicks it faster than R can react, it might actually be incremented by 2 (unlikely but perhaps feasible). The act of the button's value *changing* (incrementing) is what triggers the reaction, so you need to know what the previous values were to know which one (assuming only one) was clicked.

Try the following:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  buttonstates <- reactiveValues(one=0, two=0)
  output$mean <- renderPlotly({
    req(input$button1, input$button2)
    if (input$button1 != buttonstates$one) {
      buttonstates$one <- input$button1
      output_mean(out(), start_date(), geo(), language(), grupo(), TRUE, "button1")
    } else if (input$button2 != buttonstates$two) {
      buttonstates$two <- input$button2
      output_mean(out(), start_date(), geo(), language(), grupo(), TRUE, "button2")
    }
  })
}
```

Another option would be to separate the button-determination into
its own reactive block. The advantage of this is that it simplifies
your `renderPlotly` block:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  buttonstates <- reactiveValues(one=0) # don't need two=0
  whichbutton <- reactive({
    req(input$button1, input$button2)
    if (input$button1 != buttonstates$one) "button1" else "button2"
  })
  output$mean <- renderPlotly({
    req(whichbutton())
    output_mean(out(), start_date(), geo(), language(), grupo(), TRUE, whichbutton())
  })
}
```

(If you aren't familiar with `shiny::req`, it prevents the block from firing if the `req`uired variable is not "truthy", as defined by `shiny::isTruthy`. It's a handy way to prevent premature-firing during shiny start and/or other issues.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @r2evans. Following your explanation I solved my problem.  Thanks a lot.